# Dielectric Material with Variable or Tunable Permittivity

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields, dielectric

Is there a material or some kind of instrumental setup which is able to change its permittivity significantly thorugh some external factors, like radiation, current or temperature?

I am trying to verify a simulation code that I wrote through some more or less simple experiment where a test body changes its dielectric properties without moving or touching the test body. The change should be preferably reversible...

Do you maybe know some search terms regarding this problem, such as a relevant physical effect or process or area of physics that is concerned with this kind of behaviour?

Thank you very much! Any help is much appreciated!

Hagen

Comment: Tuneable dielectrics are indeed a thing, using ceramics that can be polarized with a dc bias to change the behavior at rf. Likely you have some in your phone.

Comment: Barium Strontium Titanate has dc bias voltage dependent permittivity, and is used in tunable capacitors (varactors).

Comment: liquid crystals, chalcogenides (stuff they use in CD-R), vanadium dioxide, gallium etc.

Comment: Thank you! Your answers put me now in the position to do much more informed websearch :)